# Error when serializing class containing List(Of OtherClass)

Tags: .net, vb.net, serialization, xml-serialization, generic-list

I found that many people have the same problem, but I haven't found how to fix it.

Assume that I have 2 classes `Employee` and `Department`

**Employee**

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Public Class Employee
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property LastName As String
    Public Property MotherName As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal str1, ByVal str2, ByVal str3)
        Name = str1
        LastName = str2
        MotherName = str3
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Department Class**

```
Public Class Department
    Public Property Employees As List(Of Employee)

    Public Sub New()
        Employees = New List(Of Employee)
    End Sub

    Public Sub WriteToXml(ByVal strXmlFilePath As String,
                           Optional ByVal encrypted As Boolean = False)
        Dim xs As New Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(Department))
        Dim sr As New StringWriter
        Dim strObject As String = String.Empty

        xs.Serialize(sr, Me)

        If encrypted Then
            Dim wrapper As Simple3Des = New Simple3Des("123")
            strObject = wrapper.EncryptData(sr.ToString)
        Else
            strObject = sr.ToString
        End If

        Using sw As New StreamWriter(strXmlFilePath)
            sw.Write(strObject)
            sw.Close()
        End Using
    End Sub

    Public Sub ReadFromXml(ByVal strXmlFilePath As String,
                           Optional ByVal encrypted As Boolean = False)
        Dim xs As New Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(Department))
        Dim strObject As String = String.Empty
        Dim micResult As New Department

        Using sr As New StreamReader(strXmlFilePath)
            strObject = sr.ReadToEnd

            If encrypted Then
                Dim wrapper As Simple3Des = New Simple3Des("123")
                strObject = wrapper.DecryptData(strObject)
            End If

            sr.Close()
        End Using

        micResult = DirectCast(xs.Deserialize(New StringReader(strObject)), Department)
        Me.Employees.AddRange(micResult.Employees)
        micResult.Dispose()
    End Sub
```

When I ran the following code

```
        Dim m As New Employee("A", "B", "C")
        Dim m1 As New Employee("D", "E", "F")
        Dim ml1 As New Department
        Dim ml2 As New Department

        ml1.Employees.Add(m)
        ml1.Employees.Add(m1)

        ml1.WriteToXml("1.xml")
```

I got an exception on `ml1.WriteToXml("1.xml")`

> There was an error reflecting type 'SerializerTest.Department'

The problem is that `Department` Class contains a `List(of Employee)`

I found many articles talking about this problem but I don't now how to achieve this.

Comment: You don't need the `Serializable` attribute if you're only dealing with XML Serialization. It is used for Binary Serialization.

Comment: That Employee class is not serializable since it doesnt have a simple ctor, there is no reason in *that* to serialize Departement - rather just serialize the Employee list, if there were some Dept props (like even a Name) its kind of silly to create an inner object and copy the elements to Me.  Just make it a Shared method returning the Department object...and a CrytoStream might be better/easier than that crypto method.

Comment: @VisualVincent it is also needed for designer serialization

Comment: @Plutonix this is an simple example the real department class contains at about 5 List and many properties. but i am trying to now how to solve this kind of problem.

Comment: @Plutonix it is solved when creating simple ctor. thx a lot

Comment: @Plutonix if you can put your comment as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The foremost problem is that `Employee` does not have a parameterless constructor:

```
Public Class Employee

    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property LastName As String
    Public Property MotherName As String

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub
    ...
```

But the serialization methods are a bit wasteful.  When deserializing, rather than copy all the data from an internal, temp object to `Me`, you can make it a `Shared` method to create and return the object to be used by the app:

```
Public Class Department
     ...
    Public Shared Function Load(strXmlFilePath As String) As Department
        Dim xs As New Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(Department))
        ' ToDo: return Nothing if file DNE
        Using fs As New FileStream(strXmlFilePath, FileMode.Open)
            Dim d As Department
            d = xs.Deserialize(fs)
            Return d
        End Using

    End Function
```

Then create/load the Department object using that method:

```
Dim d As New Department
d.Employees.Add(New Employee("ziggy", "jones", ""))
d.Employees.Add(New Employee("zoey", "smith", ""))
d.Employees.Add(New Employee("hoover", "greene", "q"))

d.WriteToXml("C:\Temp\Depts.xml")

Dim d2 = Department.Load("C:\Temp\Depts.xml")
'd2.ReadFromXml("C:\Temp\Depts.xml")

For Each emp In d2.Employees
    Console.WriteLine(emp.Name)
Next
```

All my employees made the round trip:

> ziggy
>   zoey
>   hoover